# How to draw a sector in openlayers?

Tags: openlayers

I try to use `ol.style.RegularShape`, but it can only draw triangles and squares.

```
 image: new ol.style.RegularShape({
     radius: radius,
     angle: 90,
     stroke: new ol.style.Stroke({
         color: color
     }),
     fill: new ol.style.Fill({
         color: color
     }),
     points: 3,
     rotation: 0.6
 })
```

How can I solve it?
like 
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xU6o7.jpg)

Comment: You mean polygon?

Comment: yes, but not the regular polygon.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [ol.geom.Polygon](http://openlayers.org/en/latest/apidoc/ol.geom.Polygon.html). put the coordinates of the polygon that you want to draw. If you want to draw the polygon by click, use [ol.interaction.draw](http://openlayers.org/en/latest/apidoc/ol.interaction.Draw.html) with `type: 'Polygon'`

draw sample [here](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/WOgrPe)

Comment: The shape you want is circular sector. it's not a polygon.

Comment: Thank you for your reply, I'll try it. I found a temporary method.
use [ol.style.Icon](https://openlayers.org/en/latest/apidoc/ol.style.Icon.html)